# Stata graph with no horizontal lines in the graph and no legend border

Tags: graph, latex, border, stata, legend

I am exporting my Stata graphs as *.eps in order to implement them in LaTeX. I'm using the following options:

```
xtline bhar_pct if decile==1 | decile==10 | decile==11, overlay ///graphregion(color(white)) bgcolor(white) legend(region(lwidth(none) label(1 "Portfolio 1") label(2 "Portfolio 10") label(3 "Hedge Portfolio (10 - 1)")) plot1(lpattern(solid) lwidth(medium) lcolor(gs1)) plot2(lpattern(longdash) lwidth(medium) lcolor(gs1)) plot3(lpattern("---#") lwidth(medium) lcolor(gs8)) xlabel(0 (10) 50) xtitle("") ylabel(-10 (2) 10, angle(0)) ytitle("BHAR (in %)")
```

But still: the background is white, but there are "super light blue gridlines" inside the graph as well as as the border of my legend. Moreover, the graph has an "overall" blue border as well. By now I am trimming the graph in order to remove this border, but there must be a way to create "plain" graphs?

I had to convert the *.eps file to png, but cannot post it due to lack of reputations. So here is a link to it:
http://www.converthub.com/working/done/93b7cfd46b432b1312f78912e645a5cb/aar_crisis1_dsue1.png

Comment: Please post your complete command and try to insert an image of your graph. Even better if you can reproduce your problem using one of Stata's built-in datasets. See `help sysuse`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about:

```
clear all
set more off

*----- example data -----

sysuse xtline1

xtset person day

*----- what you want -----

xtline calories, overlay graphregion(color(white)) bgcolor(white) ylabel(, nogrid) ///
    legend(region(lcolor(white)))
```

?

Comment: dear Roberto, the example from your code is perfect. there is no border, no blue line. Thank you very much! I could replicate this with my graphs.

Comment: Glad this worked for you. I find this kind of feedback satisfactory, although not optimal for this site. Consider reading http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers. If you wish, you can go back to old questions to adjust upvotes/accepts. This will increase your reputation also.